# Combining coefficients of two independent linear regression

Tags: regression, meta-analysis

I have two datasets. Dataset 1 has $P$ measurements of dependent variable $Y$ and independent variable $X_1,,,X_N$. Dataset 2 has $Q$ measurements of dependent variable $Z$ and $X_1,,,X_N$. $Y$ and $Z$ are similar but not identical variables. I want to determine which of $X's$ have significant and similar effects on both $Y$ and $Z$. I ran two sets of univariate regressions:  $Y \sim X_i$ and $Z \sim X_i$. I can compare standardized $\beta^y_i$ and $\beta^z_i$ for each $X_i$, and find those are consistents. But what is the best way to quantify consistency? 
One solution is to calculate avg : $\beta_i = \beta^y_i + \beta^z_i$.
How to quantify the significance of $\beta_i$ and significance of consistency between $\beta^y_i$  and $\beta^z_i$?

Comment: By using standardized coefficients you strongly imply the variances of all the explanatory variables in Dataset 1 are the same as the variances of all the explanatory variables in Dataset 2: is that the case?

Comment: @whuber the variance of the explanatory variables are NOT the same in the two datasets. So there is no systematic approach to combine them except visualization through scatter plot etc.?

Comment: One would have to question what combining two incomparable quantities like these standard coefficients would even mean.  Any meaningful measure of consistency would express all explanatory and response values in consistent units and go on from there.  That rules out standardizing the data sets separately.